# Lucene index Query is stopped working suddenly

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-lucene-index

We are using Cassandra 4.0 version and their Lucene jar plugin have used in the lib folder of Cassandra to run the Lucene index queries but internment the Lucene queries are not working. They suddenly stopped working. We then dropped the index and recreated it on the same table to make it work. I was not able find the root cause for the same issue when we are checking the system logs and find below error.

> ERROR [ReadStage-4] 2022-11-25 06:12:29,910 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[ReadStage-4,10,main]
> java.lang.AssertionError: null
> ERROR [ReadStage-1] 2022-11-25 06:12:33,737 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[ReadStage-1,5,main]
> java.lang.AssertionError: null

The Lucene index query stopped working suddenly.

Comment: Please include the full stack-trace (in code format)

Comment: We are using cassandra lucene  index quries in the database  some times it is not getting result as per above written mail .